# Gephi Toolkit, how to color nodes and edges

Tags: graph, toolkit, gephi

I'm trying to create and export a larger number of graphs with `Gephi`. I got the `Gephi-Toolkit` for `Java` but I have a couple of problems:

I manage to create edges/nodes but I would like to color these separately. I can’t find a function how to apply the attribute when creating the nodes and edges. I do this with the following commands:

```
Node n0 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n0");
Edge e1 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n1, n2, 1f, true);
```

I found the class **EdgeColor** in the API but this is only for the export (preview). So I would like to set the mode to original. From the API:

> An edge color type. The color of an edge can be:
>
> - SOURCE: The source node's color
> - TARGET: The target node's color
> - MIXED: An average of source and target color
> - CUSTOM: A custom color
> - ORIGINAL: The original edge color, if exist

How can I set this edge color?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm setting the color with

`node.getNodeData().setColor(float r, float g, float b)` and

`edge.getEdgeData().setColor(float r, float g, float b)`.

But the values have to be between `0.0f` and `1.0f`, so maybe you have to calculate the values via rule of three (works for me) if you have your colors between 0 and 255. The default color, I think, is 0.6f for r, g, and b. I haven't found a method for getting the node color, yet. I would store the source and target color, if changed, in a data structure (as a workaround). But maybe there is a way to get the color of a node I doesn't know.